# Set Tag To Auto-Expand

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I am new to using `Master Pages` and have just set one up, but sometimes my data expands below my `Content Place Holder`  Is their a way that I can set my `Content Place Holder`
**Master Page Syntax**

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sptScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="White" style="height: 14px;"></div>
    <div class="main" id="divMain">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="RGB123" style="height: 4px;"></div>
    <div class="GRE" style="height: 300px;">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDataForToday" CssClass="BoldTextWhiteOpenSans"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Page Usage**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    Big grid goes here
</asp:Content>
```

Below is the CSS referenced in the syntax below
**CSS**

```
.White
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 40px;
}
.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: auto;
}
.RGB123
{
    background-color: #618e1d;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 55px;
}
.GRE
{
    background-color: #333333;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by extends below the content place holder? If the grid has many rows then `MainContent` content placeholder will take up the needed space vertically.

Comment: @Sunil - that is what I would expect, but the MainContent placeholder is not expanding vertically like I want it to

Comment: Have you used some special CSS i.e styles for `MainContent`?

Comment: @Sunil - I just updated my postto show full contents of sitemaster - the issue I have is that the RGB123 & GRE are staying put and any controls I add inside of MainContent do not push RGH123 or GRE further down the page

Comment: You need to show the CSS for these classes: `White, main, RGB123, GRE`. Its some of these styles that is causing your problems.

Comment: Remove max-height from main class. Also try without any height i.e no min-height and max-height. If this doesn't solve your problem, then the html rendered in main content needs to be looked at.

Comment: @Sunil - that is causing it to expand as it should, but GRE is not moving down on the page as it should, it is staying put.

Comment: set display:block for GRE div. I mean add `display:block` to `GRE` class.

Comment: @Sunil - setting display:block to the GRE css does not cause it to move to the bottom of the page

Comment: So which divs are not aligned now? Also do you have a live URL for this page?

Comment: @Sunil - GRE is not moving down the page.  It stays put, everything else is moving like it should.

Comment: So you see the GRE div or its not visible? If possible paste the screen shot.

Comment: Remove the height attribute from GRE class.

Comment: @Sunil - removing the height attribute is still keeping it stationary.

Comment: Add a `<br />` just before the GRE div. If you had a live URL it would be easy or even a screen shot would help. Also, remove the inner div `<div style="text-align: center;">` and instead add the text-align:center to GRE class.

Comment: @Sunil adding the <br /> tag did not resolve.  Unfortunately due to sensative material I can not post a screenshot.  And it's internal only so no live link to send.

Comment: Ok.  Another thing I noticed is that your value of `4px` is too small for `RGB123`. Try to increase it to something like 20px. Actually 4px is so small that GRE div and RGB123 almost overlap and that may be the problem. You could also try adding 2 or more <br /> if changing 4px to 20 px does not work.

Comment: @Sunil - adding extra <br /> nor increasing to 20px resolved.  I posted somewhat of a screenshot above if that may or may not help

Comment: Its difficult to say now. I have looked at everything. Sorry. The screen  doesn't tell much.

Comment: post the class `BoldTextWhiteOpenSans`

Comment: @Sunil - than you for trying.  It was greatly appreciated.  Resolved most of my issue :D

Comment: Blue is back ground for what?